# Tips on how to optimize performance for some Jquery commands in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, internet-explorer

**Show/hide thumb grid is painfully slow in IE8.**

I have a thumb that operates with a category attribute on each thumb and some toggles to show the different categories. The code below handles the showing/hiding thumbs but this is extremely slow in IE and sometimes throws the "A script is slow"-warning. I guess there's no need to state that this runs very well in all other browsers.

**My question is: can you help with some performance tips? Maybe even hints a to whether it makes sense to rewrite that bit to pure Javascript?**

```
$('#cat-tab .categories-list a').live('click', function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var $target = $('#cat-tab .video-results');
        var $text = $.trim($('span', $this).text());
        $scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

        $('#cat-tab .categories-list a').removeClass('active');
        $this.addClass('active');

        $('#cat-tab .video-results .channel').removeClass('hidden');
        if($text != 'All') {
            $('#cat-tab .video-results .channel[rel!="'+$text+'"]').addClass('hidden');
        }
        $.rePage(true);

        return false;
    });
```

Comment: What plugins are you using with jQuery, as I see `$.rePage()` there.

Comment: Try commenting out certain parts of the script to determine what parts are causing the slowness (I would comment out `$.rePage(true)` first). How many elements are we talking about? (How many elements does `$target`, `$('#cat-tab .categories-list a')` etc match?)

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to me that that code there runs slowly.  How do you *know* it's that code?  I'd put some timer code in there (create a Date at the beginning and right before `return` and check the difference) to make sure, because (unless the page is really huge; how many of those ".video-results .channel" elements are there?) there's just not much work being done.

Comment: protoculous/prototype.js
protoculous/effects.js
protoculous/dragdrop.js

  <script type="text/javascript" src="/resources/um/script/protoculous/controls.js"></script>

Comment: That doesn't answer the question - what is that "$.rePage" thing?

Comment: I haven't done a elapsed time-check, but I'm positive that the lines above is where the heavy stuff goes down. There's around 130 videos.

Comment: If you have not done elapsed time checks, you cannot be "positive."

Comment: Also: install dynaTrace Ajax Edition and profile your page with that.

Comment: Tagged up jQuery - but you mention prototype in your comment, is it running both jQuery and Prototype or just Prototype?

Comment: You guys are right - it's rePage() that takes time - I'll look into that before posting anymore half assed questions.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of laboriously finding and hiding each individual thumb element from script, leverage stylesheets into doing the work for you:

```
#categories .channel { display: none; }
#categories.category-all .channel { display: block; }
#categories.category-1 .channel-1 { display: block; }
#categories.category-2 .channel-2 { display: block; }
#categories.category-3 .channel-3 { display: block; }
#categories.category-4 .channel-4 { display: block; }
```

Now you can just set the `className` of the ancestor `#categories` element, and all the thumbs inside will show/hide depending on whether they have a matching class for that category.

Comment: People generally think this to be disgusting, but an approach that works when there are like 200 different "channels" (to use this example) is to have that "display: none" style in some static block of CSS, and then have the code update a separate `<style>` element with a new rule upon page state update. In other words, the page directly updates some CSS code to make a particular one of the "channels" visible.